# set the silverlight start page

Tags: silverlight

How do I set the Startup page in Silverlight? 
Not sure if am googling for the wrong terminology or it just does not seem to be mentioned anywhere.

Cheers

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The term "Startup page" is somewhat ambiguous.  Inside a Silverlight application you probably mean one of a few things.

**The initial UserControl to load as the RootVisual**

In app.xaml.cs you will find code like :-

```
    private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        this.RootVisual = new MainPage();
    }
```

Where `MainPage` is the user control that is the initial root visual.  You can change this is your own choice.

Perhaps though you want to set the `RootVisual` to one of a number of possible choices.  In which case you would need to use `InitParams`.  Something like:-

```
    private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        Type t = Type.GetType("SilverlightApplication1." + e.InitParams["StartupPage"]);

        this.RootVisual = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
    }
```

You then need to include the InitParams value in the `<object>` tag in the host HTML:-

```
 <object  ...>
   ...
   <param name="InitParams" value="StartupPage=Page1" />
 </object
```

**Use the navigation framework**

Another approach would be needed if you building a navigation application.  In this case the `MainPage` will contain a `Frame` with a `Source` proeperty that would contain the initial URL to map.

With this type application you could specify alternative pages to load by simply adding a path following the # in the url of the page.

Comment: Yes I was referring to the initial user control to load. You're first point covers it nicely. Cheers for that!